# Passing objects between view controllers

Tags: ios, swift

So I am trying to pass some data from the current indexPath.row between two view controllers. Both of the view controllers has this:

```
    var imageFile = [PFFile]()
    var imageText = [String]()
    var username = [String]()
    var createdAt = [NSDate]()
    var objID = [String]()
    var thumbEmoji = [NSArray]()
    var loveEmoji = [NSArray]()
    var laughEmoji = [NSArray]()
    var handsEmoji = [NSArray]()
    var pooEmoji = [NSArray]()
    var comments = [NSArray]()
    var tagString = ""
```

How can I pass this in the `override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)` and get the current `indexPath.row`?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the `indexPath` and the destination controller so you can set it's data. `sender` is also the `UITableViewCell` instance. This is for default implementation, where each cell triggers the `ShowDetail` segue.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow, let controller = segue.destinationViewController as? [your_destination_controller_type] {
            //Do you thing here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Am i using collectionView, not tableView..

Comment: then you can use the cell, which is available in the `sender` parameter and get the `indexPath` through `UICollectionView`'s `indexPathForCell` method

Comment: How exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass sender as `indexPath`, you have to convert it back at `prepareForSegue` method

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifire" sender:indexPath];
}
```

And in `prepareForSegue` method goes like :

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"identifire"]) {
        NSIndexPath *ip = (NSIndexPath *)sender;
        YourTargetView *gcVC = (YourTargetView *)[segue destinationViewController];
        gcVC.passdata = [YourArray objectAtIndex:ip.row];
    }
}
```

HTH!!

Answer (score 0):

let indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest moving your data model outside of your view controllers.  That way, you don't have to pass anything.  When a controller wants to change data, it tells the data model to update it.  When a controller wants to display data, it asks the data model to provide it.

One piece of data model information then becomes "which is the current item".